# Picking random array element

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to grab a random value from this array. When I run the program it just prints 0 for x. Why isn't it printing the updated value that is returned from the function?

```
import java.util.*;
public class randomArray
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = new int[]{1,2,3};
        int x = 0;
        getRandom(myArray, x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static int getRandom(int[] array, int h) 
    {
        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
        return h;   
    }
}
```

Comment: You never modify `x`. And there's point in `h`.

Comment: What's the point of having second parameter in your `getRandom()` method?

Comment: @FarazDurrani this will not help as `getRandom()` returns its second argument not random value

Comment: @Ivan Trying to return rnd also gave me an error.

Comment: Assignment, perhaps?

Comment: You should see Gilberto's answer. And even you would use the return value of getrandom(..) it would be 0 as is the passed value h.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `getRandom()` to the following

```
public static int getRandom(int[] array) 
{
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length); //generate random index
    return array[rnd]; // get element by random index
}
```

And then call `System.out.println(getRandom(myArray));`

Comment: Thank you! That was a very fast response. So calling methods to a print statement just prints the thing that is returned to main?

Comment: Correct. Executing `System.out.println(<some method>);` will print value returned from that method.

Answer (score 1):

Java passes the parameters by value, not by reference, so the **x** value is not updated inside the getRandom method.
So when you call getRandom, the **h** variable is created and gets a copy of the value of the parameter x, that is the 0 value. Then you are returning the value of h that has a 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

Java is "pass-by-value" for primitive types. That means when you pass a number as an argument to another method, the original value will not be modified inside that method. You expect that `x` variable becomes `h` variable, but these are two different variables and updating `h` will not update 'x'.